# Prolog: Write code to manipulate a graph to find a solution at a depth of 2 when Goal Node is at a depth of 3

Tags: search, prolog, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I'm trying to write depth limited code that will manipulate the graph [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYQ6l.jpg) and find the solution node G at a depth of 2. I'm also trying to get the code to return the cost of the solution path.

So far I've gotten this:

```
solve( Node, Solution)  :-
  depthfirst( [], Node, Solution).

depthfirst( Path, Node, [Node | Path] )  :-
   goal( Node).

depthfirst( Path, Node, Sol)  :-
  s( Node, Node1, Cost),
  \+ member( Node1, Path),                % Prevent a cycle
  depthfirst( [Node | Path], Node1, Sol).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node], _)  :-
   goal( Node).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node | Sol], Maxdepth)  :-
   Maxdepth > 0,
   s( Node, Node1),
   Max1 is Maxdepth - 1,
   depthfirst2( Node1, Sol, Max1).


goal(g).
s(a,b,4).
s(a,c,5).
s(b,d,4).
s(b,e,2).
s(d,e,2).
s(d,g,1).
s(e,g,3).
s(c,e,5).
s(c,f,4).
s(f,g,7).
```

I know this will perform my standard depth-first search, However, I'm not sure how to go about manipulating it to find the solution at a depth of 2. I'm not even sure if my code is even partially right or if the code is just complete spaghetti.

Any help would be fantastic, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How is the node `g` a "solution at a depth of 2"? What is the query you are interested in, and how do you define depth?

If I take "depth" to be the length of the solution list (maybe you mean this length - 1) and start searching at node `a`, your code correctly enumerates all solutions:

```
?- solve(a, Solution).
Solution = [g, e, d, b, a] ;
Solution = [g, d, b, a] ;
Solution = [g, e, b, a] ;
Solution = [g, e, c, a] ;
Solution = [g, f, c, a] ;
false.
```

You can search by increasing path length up to a certain limit as follows:

```
?- between(0, 10, N), length(Solution, N), solve(a, Solution).
N = 4,
Solution = [g, d, b, a] ;
N = 4,
Solution = [g, e, b, a] ;
N = 4,
Solution = [g, e, c, a] ;
N = 4,
Solution = [g, f, c, a] ;
N = 5,
Solution = [g, e, d, b, a] ;
false.
```

But there is no solution of length 2.

Comment: This is the task I was assigned. I know there has to be a way to manipulate the code to find G at a depth of 2 as we were given the solution in some notes in the past, but no amount of digging through them is returning any results for me. Is there any way you think I could solve this?

Comment: The exact question asked is "_Write a depth limited code to manipulate the graph presented (_**I have provided it above**_) and find the solution at depth 2. Your code should return the cost of the solution path._"